# How to reverse findProgramAddress

Tags: web3.js, publickey

Is it possible to reverse `PublicKey.findProgramAddress` method?

I.E. from an address find the seeds and the programId that were used for this address

Answer (score 1):

**No**

finding a program address uses SHA256 and loops through bumps in order to find a valid PDA (off curve), reversing a SHA256 is impossible.